Solving an LPP of an inconsistent set of linear equations.
A company owns two flour mills ($A, B$) which have different production capacities for high (H), medium (M) and low (L) grade flour. This company has entered contract supply flour to a firm every week with $8, 12, \text{ & } 24$ quintals of H, M and L grade respectively. It costs $1000, 800$ dollars per day to run mill A and mill B respectively. On a day, mill A produces $6, 2, \text { and } 4$ quintals of H, M and L grade flour respectively. Mill B produces $2, 4, \text{ and } 12$ quintals of H, M, and L grade flour respectively. How many days per week should each mill be operated in order to meet the contract order most economically?
The decision variables are: $x_1:$ mill A, $x_2:$ mill B. Then, have the structural constraints' matrix as:
$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  6 & 2  \\
  2 & 4 \\
  4 & 12 
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  8 \\
  12 \\
  24
\end{array}\right)$
Taking $R1 - 3*R2, R3 - 2*R2$ get:
$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & -10  \\
  2 & 4 \\
  0 & 4
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  -28 \\
  12 \\
  0
\end{array}\right)$
As expected, having three unique/distinct equations to solve for two unknowns, leads us to a set of inconsistent equations, i.e. have:

$-10x_2 = -28 \implies x_2 = 2.8$
$4x_2 = 0 \implies x_2 = 0$

But, then need to assume a value for $x_2.$ But, how to assume a value for $x_2$ is unclear, as it appears in three linear equations.

The result of Moos linear programming is $x_1=0.4, x_2=2.8$. For instance, the first constraint is fulfilled: $6\cdot 0.4+2\cdot 2.8=2.4+5.6=8$

@Moo My resource constraint matrix, is the same, but only for the structural constraints, i.e. ignores the last two non-negativity constraints of yours. But, am still stuck, and do not know how calculus arrived at the given answer, when $x_2$ has to be assumed.

@jiten Usually you apply the simplex method to solve such linear problems. In this case you can solve the problem graphically as well.

@callculus42 How simplex is useful here, is unclear. I mean what property of simplex method makes it useful for an inconsistent set of linear equations.

@Moo Then by simplex, can have variable value of a D.V. But, that means that the solution is searched at some inside region, rather than on the boundary. Is it optimal to search in the inside region?

@Moo Please send some reference for your second line of the last comment. Am confused, as have read that the optimal solution occurs only at the boundary only.

As stated in the comment, this is a linear programming problem.
To solve for the corner points, we still have to consider the inequalities, i.e., we can't just drop all the inequalities. To find a corner for your case, we have to set two independent inequalities to equalities and check for the feasibility of the other constraint. In the worst case, we have $\binom52$ possibilities.
What simplex algorithm does is it travels from corner to corner so that we do not enumerate through all the solutions. In the worst case, we could have visited all the corner points. However, for most problems, it is quite efficient. There are also other methods besides
For this case, since it is just a two-dimensional problem, we can visualize it.

It is just the intersection of the first two constraints for this particular problem. Now, you can solve for a system of linear equations.

Sorry, am confused as it is unclear how the question of solving, using the Simplex method, the inconsistent set of linear equations, is addressed by your answer. Hope that some additional material would suffice, to your given answer.

your mistake is set all the inequalities to equalities simultaneously. At BFS, we only set some of the inequalities to be equalities.

Kindly see my new post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4970185/424260

Please elaborate your last point, with the help of the example given by you: say by taking the first bfs, in the example - to show which inequalities are kept as inequalities, and which are taken as equalities. Am totally in dark about what you want to say.

I am rushing to meet multiple deadlines. Will get back to you.

graphically, we can see only the first two constraints are active.
