Logic behind pivoting, and minimum ratio in the Simplex method.
Please vet my understanding of the subject, as stated below:
Given some LPP, for a maximization problem, with no slack variables, let the one made by me, as shown below; in the form $AX=B,$ with the matrix $B$ showing the resource constraints, the matrix $A$ showing the coefficients (resource used/unit of the variable):
The objective function is: Maximize $z = 150x_1 + 240x_2$
Resource constraint matrix, showing the three structural constraints ($C_1, C_2, C_3$) is:
$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  50 & 24  \\
  30 & 33 \\
  10 & 17 \\
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{array}\right)\leq
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  240 \\
  210 \\
  450 \\
\end{array}\right)$
with $$C1: 50x_1 + 24x_2 \le 240,$$ $$C2: 30x_1 + 33x_2 \le 210,$$ $$C3: 10x_1 + 17x_2 \le 450.$$
And, the two non-negativity constraints: $C4: x_1\geq 0, C5: x_2\geq 0.$
Its augmented (added slack variables, for the maximization problem) LPP would have three slack variables added, i.e. $x_3 (=s_1), x_4(=s_2), x_5(=s_3),$ i.e. one for each of the structural constraints. Also, three new non-negativity constraints are added: $C4: x_3(=s_1)\geq 0, C5: x_4(=s_2)\geq 0, C6: x_5(=s_3)\geq 0.$
The LPP problems of practical interest are having a lot many decision variables (dv) (let, $n$), and similarly a lot many structural (functional) constraints (let, $m$).
In the algebraic approach, of solving LPP, using the Simplex method; need have the following properties:

No basic infeasible solution is evaluated, i.e. no need to evaluate the $C^{m+n}_m -$ (the number of bfs).
Progressively obtains better and better feasible solutions.
Identifies the optimal solution, as soon as it is reached; without a need to evaluate the rest of the basic feasible solutions (bfs).

The algebraic method has to algebraically find the intersections of the shared-edge constraints. 
The property being used, for achieving $(1)$ is that the first intersection, along any dimension is a bfs (basic feasible solutions), while the later intersections are bis (basic infeasible solutions).
This job of finding the leaving variable, is done by finding the minimum ratio.

Say, as shown the above LPP, for the intersection of the structural constraints: $C1, C2, C3$ with the non-negativity constraint ($C4: x\ge 0$) have the first intersection: $a$ as a bfs, while the rest intersections with $C4$ (i.e. $b,c$), are bis points.
Similarly, for the intersection of the three structural constraints, with the second non-negativity constraint ($C5: y\ge 0$) yields the first intersection point: $d$ as a bfs, while the rest intersections with $C5,$ (i.e. $e,f$) as bis.
The initial point has the coordinates: $(0,0,x_3(=s_1)=b_1,x_4(=s_2)=b_2,x_5(=s_3)=b_3),$ where $b_i$ are the resource constraints in the $B$ matrix, with $i$ denoting the $i$-th row.
The first iteration has the entering variable as $x_1,$ while the leaving variable is: $s_1,$ as the bfs: $a$ is found by the intersection of $C1, C4;$ where the common (shared) variable is the $dv: x_1.$
Algebraically, the leaving variable is found by taking the minimum ratio, of the constraints (i.e., the rhs) of each of the three structural constraints, with their corresponding coefficient of the shared variable, i.e. $x_1.$

Doubt #1: The maximum coefficient in the objective function (for a maximization problem) helps in deciding the entering variable, as it shows the maximum increase of profit, for a maximization problem. But, still feel that some more logic should lie under this.

Then divide the coefficients of all the variables, in the constraint of the intersection of the entering dv, & the leaving dv; by the coefficient of the entering variable.
This makes the entering variable's coefficient as $1.$
Next, the pivoting method is followed to eliminate the entering variable, from all other constraints, except in which it enters.

Doubt #2: The logic behind the pivoting operation, is to reduce the dimension (by one) of the other (structural) constraints. Though the dimension of the constraint, for the entering variable is not
affected. Am not totally clear, about how this reduction of dimension of the other constraints helps in finding solution. It seems that the job done by pivoting is similar to that of finding the minimum-ratio, and could get no further.

Tried to solve the above LPP, using the Simplex method, to understand the above issues better;  but seems of no avail.
Initial iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} = \text{ Cost of i-th B.V., } i\leq m & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
s_1  & 0  & 240 & 50 & 24 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{240}{10} = 10\\ \hline
s_2  & 0  & 210 & 30 & 33 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{210}{33} = \frac{70}{11} \approx 6.37\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 450 & 10 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{450}{17} \approx 26.5 \\ \hline
z=0   & & Z_j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
First iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
s_1  & 0  & 240-24*\frac{70}{11}=\frac{960}{11} & 50-24*\frac{10}{11} = \frac{310}{11} & 0 & 1 & -\frac{24}{33}=-\frac8{11} & 0 & \frac{960}{310} \approx 3.1\\ \hline
x_2  & 240  & \frac{210}{33}= \frac{70}{11} & \frac{30}{33}= \frac{10}{11} & \frac{33}{33}=1 & 0 & \frac{1}{33} & 0 & \frac{70}{10}=7\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 450-17*\frac{70}{11}=\frac{3760}{11} & 10 -17*\frac{10}{11}=-\frac{60}{11} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{17}{33} & 1 & N.A. \\ \hline
z  & & Z_j & 0 & 240 & 0 & \frac{240}{33} = \frac{80}{11} & 0 &   \\ \hline
=240*\frac{70}{11} & & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
= \frac{16800}{11} \approx 1527.28 & & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{80}{11} & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Second iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
x_1  & 150 & \frac{960}{11}*\frac{11}{310}=\frac{96}{31} & 1 & 0 & \frac{11}{310} & -\frac{8}{310} & 0 & \\ \hline
x_2  & 240 & \frac{70}{11} -\frac{96}{31}*\frac{10}{11}=\frac{2170-960}{31*11}=\frac{110}{31}& 0 & 1 & -\frac{11}{310}*\frac{10}{11} = -\frac{1}{31} & \frac{1}{33}+\frac{8}{310}*\frac{10}{11} = \frac{31*11+8*33}{31*33*11} = \frac{607}{31*33*11} & 0 & \\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & \frac{3760}{11} +\frac{96}{31}*\frac{60}{11}= \frac{3760*31+5760}{31*11}=\frac{116560+5760}{31*11}=\frac{11120}{31}& 0 & 0 & 0+\frac{11}{310}*\frac{60}{11}= \frac{6}{31} & -\frac{17}{33}-\frac{8}{310}*\frac{60}{11}= -\frac{17*31*11+48*33}{33*31*11} =-\frac{5797+2904=8701}{31*33*11}=-\frac{791}{31*33}& 1 & \\ \hline
z  & & Z_j & 150 & 240 & \frac{15*11=165}{31} & -\frac{8*15}{31}+\frac{240*607}{33*31*11}= -\frac{120}{31}+\frac{80*607}{11*31*11}=\frac{-120*121+80*607}{31*121}=\frac{34040}{31*121} & 0 &   \\ \hline
=150*\frac{96}{31}+240*\frac{110}{31} & & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
=\frac{14400+26400}{31}= \frac{40800}{31} \approx 1316.13 & & C_j - Z_j & 0 & 0 & -\frac{165}{31} & -\frac{34040}{31*121} & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Edit As my Simplex method, does not help in not moving on to the second bfs ($g$), inspite of lesser value for the objective function, i.e. $z.$
So, have tried to incorporate the changes suggested by the link, given in the comment by @Moo.

Doubt #3: The change suggested, as per the link, though without any reason to process the objective function too, as the other rows; i.e. the one apart from the row (constraint) of the entering decision variable.

The change is to have an extra row of the objective function, with effectively no need for $C_j - Z_j,$ as it did not help. But, would still keep it for some more time, to see its futility in certain situation(s), and to identify those situations.
The change needed is to also process the objective function ($z$), as
Initial iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
z  &   & & -150 & -240 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & 240 & 50 & 24 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{240}{10} = 10\\ \hline
s_2  & 0  & 210 & 30 & 33 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{210}{33} = \frac{70}{11} \approx 6.37\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 450 & 10 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{450}{17} \approx 26.5 \\ \hline
z=0   & & Z_j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
First iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
z  &   & & -150 +240*\frac{10}{11} = \frac{750}{11}& -240+240=0 & 0 & \frac{240}{33}=\frac{80}{11} & 0 & \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & 240-24*\frac{70}{11}=\frac{960}{11} & 50-24*\frac{10}{11} = \frac{310}{11} & 0 & 1 & -\frac{24}{33}=-\frac8{11} & 0 & \frac{960}{310} \approx 3.1\\ \hline
x_2  & 240  & \frac{210}{33}= \frac{70}{11} & \frac{30}{33}= \frac{10}{11} & \frac{33}{33}=1 & 0 & \frac{1}{33} & 0 & \frac{70}{10}=7\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 450-17*\frac{70}{11}=\frac{3760}{11} & 10 -17*\frac{10}{11}=-\frac{60}{11} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{17}{33} & 1 & N.A. \\ \hline
z  & & Z_j & 0 & 240 & 0 & \frac{240}{33} = \frac{80}{11} & 0 &   \\ \hline
=240*\frac{70}{11} & & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
= \frac{16800}{11} \approx 1527.28 & & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{80}{11} & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
As there is no negative value left in the top row, corresponding to the objective function ($z$); so it finds the solution as the bfs: $d.$
This solution gives a better (optimal) objective function ($z$) value, as compared to the one given by earlier version of the Simplex method, that chooses bfs: $g.$
Edit 2 Took clue from the site here (though, it computes $Z_j-C_j$) and see that had missed the computation $Z_1.$ 
The computation of $Z_1$ leads to stopping the computation at the first iteration only; by using the first method too.
Initial iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} = \text{ Cost of i-th B.V., } i\leq m & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
s_1  & 0  & 240 & 50 & 24 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{240}{10} = 10\\ \hline
s_2  & 0  & 210 & 30 & 33 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{210}{33} = \frac{70}{11} \approx 6.37\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 450 & 10 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{450}{17} \approx 26.5 \\ \hline
z=0   & & Z_j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
First iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
s_1  & 0  & 240-24*\frac{70}{11}=\frac{960}{11} & 50-24*\frac{10}{11} = \frac{310}{11} & 0 & 1 & -\frac{24}{33}=-\frac8{11} & 0 & \frac{960}{310} \approx 3.1\\ \hline
x_2  & 240  & \frac{210}{33}= \frac{70}{11} & \frac{30}{33}= \frac{10}{11} & \frac{33}{33}=1 & 0 & \frac{1}{33} & 0 & \frac{70}{10}=7\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 450-17*\frac{70}{11}=\frac{3760}{11} & 10 -17*\frac{10}{11}=-\frac{60}{11} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{17}{33} & 1 & N.A. \\ \hline
z  & & Z_j &  240*\frac{10}{11} = \frac{2400}{11} & 240 & 0 & \frac{240}{33} = \frac{80}{11} & 0 &   \\ \hline
=240*\frac{70}{11} & & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
= \frac{16800}{11} \approx 1527.28 & & C_j - Z_j & 150 - \frac{2400}{11} =\frac{1650-2400}{11}=\frac{-750}{11} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{80}{11} & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Hence, no further iteration is possible, as no positive value for $C_j - Z_j$ exists.

Doubt #4: But, still am not clear about the equivalence between:
a) the first (it takes the $C_j - Z_j$ criteria) method: that does not do the elimination using the pivot (in the entering variable) of the objective function, in each iteration; &
b) the second method (that takes the most negative value in the objective function, modified using the pivot).
As the first method is having $C_j$ as fixed, so there must be found an equivalence between $-Z_j$ row (in the first method) & the modified $z$ coefficients (in the second method).


https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/linear-programming/simplex-method-calculator/?z=150x_1%2B240x_2&max=on&c=50x_1%2B24x_2%3C%3D240%2C30x_1%2B33x_2%3C%3D210%2C10x1%2B17x2%3C%3D450%2Cx_1%3E%3D0%2Cx_2%3E%3D0&m=m

@Moo My solution also shows the first iteration to get the final (and the next, after the initial point, of origin) as on the $x_2$ axis, with the objective function ($z$) value as: $16800/11\approx 1527.28;$ which is more than the second iteration's value of $\frac{40800}{31} \approx 1316.1,$ in the second iteration. But, how to see that the next step would not be taken, when the value of $C_j - Z_j$ would have the value of $150,$ under the $x_1$ column at the end of the first iteration?

@Moo Can you please tell the reason why inclusion of the objective function, for performing reduction using the pivoting operation, applied to the row (constraint) of the entering decision variable, helps in finding the correct bfs. Will edit soon by adding a row, above the rows for the basis variables; but the logic still evades. The column titled: 'Value of B.V.', still does processing, but of the rhs (resource constraint) of the rows, for the structural constraints. Am unclear how the objective function's processing, is indeed a must.

@Moo Please see my 'Edit 2', and the Doubt #4; that gels with my last comment.


There are a few types of implementation of Simplex algorithm. I am more familiar with other convention but the idea is similar.

From the website that is shared in the comment: Their convention is to use the tableau to track the following where in each iteration, the basis $B$ is different. Also, the objective is in minimization, hence the sign is reversed.
\begin{array}{|l|l|} \hline
c^T-c_B^TB^{-1}A &  -c_B^TB^{-1}b   \\ \hline
B^{-1}A & B^{-1}b  \\ \hline
\end{array}

The appended row usually represents the reduced cost $c^T-c_B^TB^{-1}A$, it is the rate of improvement if we were to choose that as the entrance variable. That is why usually the maximum rate of improvement is usually chosen.

The minimum ratio is the distance that we can travel without leaving the feasible space along the new direction.

The idea of pivoting is to perform a change of basis. From one iteration to the next iteration, only one column of the basis matrix is changed. By doing pivoting (i.e. a series of row operations), effectively, we are computing the inverse of the new basis matrix.

For the feasible set defined by the constraint where $b\ge 0$ elementwise,  $$Ax\le b, x \ge 0$$
at the beginning of the iteration, if we pick the original decision variables to be $0$, then the indices of the basis are from the slack variables where $c_B=0$, hence the reduced cost is equal to the cost $c$.

At the beginning of the iteration, the table is of the form of


$$[c^T, 0] - g^T[A, b]$$
where $g=c_B^TB^{-1}$ where $B$ is a basis. Now, the pivot row is of the form of $h^T[A, b]$, where $h^T$ is a $l$-th row of $B^{-1}$ where $l$ is the index of the pivot row. Adding a multiplier to the first row would give us again the form of
$$[c^T, 0] - p^T[A, b]$$
and it can be shown that $p^T=c_{\bar{B}}^T\bar{B}^{-1}$ where $\bar{B}$ is the new basis matrix.

Hence the idea of the simplex algorithm is to find directions to travel from BFS to BFS improving its solution each time, when there are no further improvement possible, that is the optimal solution. The improvement in each iteration has been captured in the first row. The tableau is just an efficient method to keep track of the data and pivoting is used to update the basis and to avoid explicit inverse calculation.

Reference: Introduction to Linear Optimization
